# How to get the co-ordinates of the text recogonized from Image using OCR in python

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to get the coordinates or positions of text character from an Image using Tesseract.
I want to know the exact pixel position, so that i can click that text using some other tool.

Edit :

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import csv

img = 'E:\\OCR-DATA\\sample.jpg'
imge = Image.open(img)
    data=pytesseract.image_to_string(imge,lang='eng',boxes=True,config='hocr')

print(data)
```

`data` contains recognized text with box boundary value. But i am not sure , how to use that boundary value to get the co-ordinates of the text.

Value of the `data` variable is as follows:

```
O 100 356 115 373 0

u 117 356 127 368 0

t 130 356 138 372 0

p 141 351 152 368 0

u 154 356 164 368 0

t 167 356 175 371 0
```

Comment: Sorry , i am new to this forum. didn't know the rules. Now added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the coordinates of the bounding box in every line.

From: [Training Tesseract – Make Box Files](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/Make-Box-Files.html)

character, left, bottom, right, top, page

So for each character you get the character, followed by its bounding box characters, followed by the 0-based page number.

Answer (score 5):

you can try This:

```
img = 'tes.jpg'
imge = Image.open(img)
data=pytesseract.image_to_boxes(imge)

print(data)
```

This will directly give you the result Like:

```
T 22 58 52 97 0
H 62 58 95 96 0
R 102 58 135 97 0
E 146 57 174 97 0
A 184 57 216 96 0
D 225 56 258 96 0
```